# (Background-color) switch isn't working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm using the following code to turn the color of a guitar string first to red on the first click, then lightblue on the second click, and so on back and fourth between the two colors. The string turns red on the first click, but remains red with following clicks and I don't understand why.

```
var string = document.getElementById("a-string");
if (string.backgroundColor !== "red") {
  string.style.backgroundColor = "red";
} else {
  string.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
}
```

Cam anyone see why this shouldn't work as I expect?

Comment: Change `if (string.backgroundColor !== …` to `if (string.style.backgroundColor !== …`

Comment: Wow, thanks, sorry i'm a noob and should have spotted that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code has few error. An error is `string.backgroundColor !== "red"`. It should be `string.style.backgroundColor !== "red"`

```
var string = document.getElementById("a-string");
if (string.style.backgroundColor !== "red")  {
  string.style.backgroundColor = "red";
} 
else {
  string.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = document.getElementById("a-string");
if (string.style.backgroundColor !== "red") {
  string.style.backgroundColor = "red";
} else {
  string.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
}
```

```css
div{
font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a-string"> A Sample Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remark**

Shorten it with `classList.toggle()`. Set a default background color to an element. **Toggle** it with a class that contains the **other** background color.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button"),
  div = document.querySelector("div");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  div.classList.toggle("bg-red");
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.bg-red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<button id="btn">Toggle background color</button>
```